# removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `li` list and this list working `data-project-id`

I want to click `list_title` `removeClass` `e` "open" but not working.

tip : `toggleClass` not working.

```
<div class="project-side-list scrollbar-inner">
   <ul id="sortable">
      <li data-project-id="1">
         <div class="list-title">Content</div>
           <div class="list-project-detail-content">
           </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "[data-project-id]", function() {
  var e = $(this),
    list = $(".project-side-list ul li "),
    list_title = $(".project-side-list ul li .list-title");

  if (e.hasClass("open")) {

    $(list_title).click(function() {    
      e.removeClass('open');
    });

  } else {    
    list.removeClass("open");
    e.addClass("open");
  }
});
```

Comment: so i want to click li open box and click li top remove open class. Now, when you click anywhere on the box, it closes.

Comment: don't nest event listeners inside other event handlers unless you really know what you are doing and have a good reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your html is invalid, you didn't close your `<li>` tag.

Here is working example, if you want to dynamically load your list later on you can use delegate function.

```js
      
function openToggler() {
  var _this = $(this);

  var element = _this.closest('li[data-project-id]');
  var elementId = element.attr('data-project-id');

  $('.project-side-list li[data-project-id]').not('[data-project-id="' + elementId + '"]').removeClass('open');

  element.toggleClass('open');
}


$('.list-title').click(openToggler);
//$('.project-side-list').delegate('.list-title', 'click', openToggler);
```

```css
li {
 color: red;
}

li.open {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    
<div class="project-side-list scrollbar-inner">
   <ul id="sortable">
      <li data-project-id="1">
         <div class="list-title">Content</div>
           <div class="list-project-detail-content">
           </div>
      </li>
      <li data-project-id="2">
         <div class="list-title">Example</div>
           <div class="list-project-detail-content">
           </div>
      </li>
      <li data-project-id="3">
         <div class="list-title">Example Content</div>
           <div class="list-project-detail-content">
           </div>
      </li>      
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for answer , but  open class <li data-project-id="1" class="open"> here is working.  i trying this

Comment: yea this working but real problem; click li add open class and content showing. but when i click content close li . my all problem this. when i click content not remove class. can you disable list-project-detail-content click or i dont know :)

Comment: so click anywhere inside li remove class

Comment: I've updated my answer. Look at it now. Now when you click `.list-title` class, it will look for closest parent `li[data-project-id]` and toggle class `.open`. Is this the result you wanted?

Comment: yea thanks bro. thats working but have simple problem. when i click first li then click second li . but not close first li .

Comment: Now it does not close first li if you click second one.

Comment: yea, when i click first li then second li . not close first li.

Comment: hey bro , last code have problem , now first li click and second li frist li close okay...  i have still first problem . click list-item open but not close again click list-item :)

Comment: So you want to close li when you double click it?

Comment: you add $('.project-side-list li[data-project-id]').removeClass('open'); this code then not working click add and click remove. click open okay but not remove again click.

Comment: your last code true but yes and double click add and remove .

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to do it.

```
$('.list-title').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('open')
})
```

http://codepen.io/iLavs/pen/YZBeMd